# How to handle selection sets of grammars that have multiple derivation trees

Tags: parsing, nlp

I need to write a parse table for a grammar that has lambda expressions and multiple derivation trees. I am having trouble finding examples of parse tables for grammars with lambda expressions. How should I start?

My attempt at the selection sets are as follows:

S-> ABCe = {e,b,c,d}.

(A->bB = {b}, A->lambda, B->cC ={c}, A->lambda, B->lambda, C->d = {d}, A->lambda, B-> lambda, C goes to lambda = {e}).

A-> bB = {b}

A-> lambda = {c,d,e}

B-> cC = {c}

B-> lambda = {d,e}

C-> d = {d}

C-> lambda = {d}

There are two problems I am having:

1) I don't know what to write to define lambda in the parse table or the actual parse code.

2) If lambda expressions are dependent on what follows in the string, then the current token would determine what is popped off, right? For example, if S goes to ABCe, and the current token is b, then would I push(e) and push(C)? I also realized something else for the lambdas just now. The selection sets for B are mutually inclusive. So, for instance, only if the current token at A is b would I push 'B,' if the current token is c,d, or e, I would just pop(). I'm really not sure how to go about writing it, this is just my thought process. But is it allowed to use the selection set in place of the actual grammar rule?